# PCA, test for eigen values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, pca, interpretation

Let's say I have a matrix $X$ with $4$ variables and $n$ observations and I run PCA, so I compute the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the sample covariance matrix, and then I test $H_0: \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_4$, and I find that I don't reject $H_0$. So I don't have evidence to say that there's a pair of different eigenvalues. What can I say about the estimation of the principal components  $\hat{v}_i = \text{eigenvectors}\left(\widehat{\text{cov}}(X)^T\right)(X_i-\bar{X})$?

Comment: A lot can be said--but do you want an answer that utilizes *only* the stated information?  In that case, the components are completely indeterminate.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I will like to draw a conclusion only based on the fact that I don't reject the test. What do you mean by "completely indeterminate"?

Comment: Any orthogonal frame could be the principal components.

Comment: @whuber so in that case the four eigenvectors of the covariance matrix are not the principal directions, but any four orthogonal vectors would give the principal components?

Comment: When you cannot reject the hypothesis that all eigenvalues are degenerate, that is tantamount to saying *any* orthogonal basis qualifies as a series of principal components.  To put it another way, you are interpreting the specific PCs that were found as possibly resulting purely from noise rather than reflecting any underlying structure.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your answer, could you please add more details? maybe a math proof on why the eigenvectors don't care in this case?

Comment: I don't want it to seem like there's some obscure insight here: I'm just applying basic linear algebra.  Good search words are "degenerate eigenvalues."